# Keystore for LDAP Login Module

Tags: ssl, authentication, ldap, certificate, worklight-security

I am using the LDAP Login module to secure access to the Worklight Console. The ldap:// access works. However, I need to access LDAP over SSL i.e., using ldaps://. I am trying to find out the key-store into which to provision the LDAP server side public-keys certificate. There are two possibilities, namely:

- the default keystore built into the worklight war file
- the keystore defined for use by Liberty Profile.

There does not appear to be any documentation on which keystore is used by the LDAP Login Module.

Any pointers?

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keystore is often even lower level than you suggest and based upon the cacerts in the JRE/JVM's lib\security directory.